Keyboard not Visible in bottom Sheet Dialog
I'm facing an issue with a nested BottomSheetDialog in my Android app. The first method, showFilterBottomSheet(), creates a BottomSheetDialog with filters like class and section. From this sheet, you can open another BottomSheetDialog using the method showMultiSelectBottomSheet(), which contains a search EditText for filtering items. The problem is that when the second bottom sheet appears, the keyboard does not show up when focusing on the EditText (ID: searchEditText).
private void showFilterBottomSheet() {

        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(FeeDefaulters.this);
        View bottomSheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_filters, null);

        campusInputLayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.campusInputLayout);
        classInputLayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.classInputLayout);
        sectionInputLayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.sectionInputLayout);
        campusAutoCompleteTextView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.campusAutoCompleteTextView);
        classAutoCompleteTextView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.classAutoCompleteTextView);
        sectionAutoCompleteTextView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.sectionAutoCompleteTextView);
        buttonApplyFilters = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.buttonApplyFilters);

        updateSelectedItemsText(campusAutoCompleteTextView, selectedCampuses);
        updateSelectedItemsText(classAutoCompleteTextView, selectedClasses);
        updateSelectedItemsText(sectionAutoCompleteTextView, selectedSections);

        campusAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> showMultiSelectBottomSheet("Campus", allCampuses, selectedCampuses, campusAutoCompleteTextView));
        classAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> showMultiSelectBottomSheet("Class", allClasses, selectedClasses, classAutoCompleteTextView));
        sectionAutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> showMultiSelectBottomSheet("Section", allSections, selectedSections, sectionAutoCompleteTextView));

        buttonApplyFilters.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(FeeDefaulters.this, "Filters Applied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadDataForTables();
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        });

        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }

    private void showMultiSelectBottomSheet(String filterType, List<Campus_info> allItems, List<Campus_info> selectedItems, TextView textViewToUpdate) {
        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(FeeDefaulters.this);
        View bottomSheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_multiselect, null);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMultiSelect);
        Button buttonApplyMultiSelect = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.buttonApplyMultiSelect);
        ImageButton closebtn = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
        EditText searchEditText = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
        CheckBox selectAllCheckbox = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.selectAllCheckbox);

        closebtn.setOnClickListener(v -> bottomSheetDialog.dismiss());
        bottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE
        );

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        MultiSelectAdapter adapter = new MultiSelectAdapter(allItems, selectedItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        selectAllCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            adapter.selectAll(isChecked);
        });

        adapter.setOnSelectionChangedListener(selectedItemsCount -> {
            selectAllCheckbox.setChecked(selectedItemsCount == allItems.size());
        });

        buttonApplyMultiSelect.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            updateSelectedItemsText(textViewToUpdate, adapter.getSelectedItems());
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        });

        bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(dialogInterface -> {
            BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialogInterface;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (bottomSheet != null) {
                BottomSheetBehavior<?> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }

            searchEditText.postDelayed(() -> {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) searchEditText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null) {
                    imm.showSoftInput(searchEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
                searchEditText.requestFocus();
            }, 1000);
        });

        // Search functionality
        searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        });

        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }


I've set the softInputMode using SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE, but it doesn't seem to help. The EditText gets focus, but the keyboard doesn't appear.
